# How can I copy the state in react without reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I want to copy the state like this:

```
let copy = this.state.foo
copy.push('bar')
```

the state copied correctly, but with its reference, and when I change 'copy' the main state changes.

What should I do to avoid this change?

Comment: Shallow copy with `.slice()`

Comment: The mentioned copy array duplicate answer is just copying array in plain js.  React best practice is NOT to mutate the state.  @JonasWilms

Comment: @fabricioG "just copying array" is "NOT mutating the state" ?

Comment: In the example the question has he is specifically referencing the main stage changes.  That's why I'm saying isn't that encouraging mutation of the original state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**array spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) or [**`Array.concat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to make a shallow clone, and add new items as well):

```js
const state = {
  foo: ['bar']
};

const copy = [...state.foo, 'bar'];

console.log(copy === state.foo); // false
```

Comment: Oh, man, My problem did not solve
let me specify more I have a state that named bar 
and I have a function named addBar and this function add the last item of the bar to the bar 
but I want to copy it without reference
I do what you said 
but it didn't work for me

Comment: You should add more code.

Comment: ``    addBar = () => {
    let bar = [...this.state.bars,{...this.state.bars[this.state.bars.length - 1]}]
    this.setState({
      bars:bar
    })
  }
``
this code must add the last item of the bar to the bar 
but it doesn't work

Comment: In the question would be nicer.

Comment: Is there any way for me to send the whole code for you ??

Comment: It seems like you clone the state.bars, and the last items of bars. And then without changing anything, you set it back to the state. Since you don't change anything, What are you trying to achieve? In addition, you should use setState with an updater function.

Comment: @mahdi - add whatever seems relevant to the question, to the question. In addition, please explain why you are doing it at all.

Comment: For futur visitor, I found the correct answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value
You'll need to understand your need with shallow vs deep copy.